# Swift - Trouble with getting nil when setting values in between functions

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, core-location, cllocationmanager

Hi I seem to only be able to get nil as my location variable while I'm writing a simple location receiving class. I've searched stack overflow for a while and tried many solutions but I can't seem to fix it.

Below is my code. I'm trying to methods, one is to set the variables in a struct in my didUpdateLocations method. The other is just to update a variable userLocation. Both are just giving my nil at the moment and I can't figure out why.

```
class SendLocation:  NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{


var userLocation: CLLocation? = nil
var locationManager:CLLocationManager!


struct LocationStruct{
    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees?, longitude:CLLocationDegrees?
}

var locationStruct = LocationStruct()


func sendLocationPost(){
    determineCurrentLocation()
    print(userLocation) // This is nil
    print(locationStruct.latitude) // This is nil
    print(locationStruct.longitude) // This is nil

}

func determineCurrentLocation(){
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    userLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    print(userLocation) // This IS NOT nil
    locationStruct.latitude=userLocation?.coordinate.latitude
    locationStruct.longitude=userLocation?.coordinate.longitude

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help as I know it will be something simple/silly

Comment: Where and when do you call `sendLocationPost`?

Comment: Which prints first, the nil or the non-nil?

Comment: @PhillipMills MillsNow that you mention it the nils print first

Comment: Makes sense.  Until there's a call to `didUpdateLocations`, you can't assume locations have been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of understanding that *things take time*. You are forging ahead as if starting to get a location gives you a location instantly. But it doesn't:

```
func sendLocationPost(){
    determineCurrentLocation()
    // so now things start... but they take _time_...!
    print(userLocation) // This is nil
    // because it's _too soon!_
    // ...
}
```

When you first call `determineCurrentLocation`, it takes a long time for the sensors to warm up and for a good location to arrive:

```
func determineCurrentLocation(){
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        // SLOWLY... things now start to happen
    }
}
```

At last, after some significant time, maybe, just maybe, we finally start to get some updates, and after some more time, maybe they are not nil:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    userLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    print(userLocation) // This IS NOT nil
    locationStruct.latitude=userLocation?.coordinate.latitude
    locationStruct.longitude=userLocation?.coordinate.longitude

}
```

*Now* we've got a location. But meanwhile your code in `sendLocationPost` ended long ago, and got `nil`.

Comment: This is a very good answer thanks. I didn't think about startUpdatingLocations() taking time.

Comment: More importantly than getting the location taking time is that it happens asynchronously, so execution can proceed while it happens.

Comment: @BallpointBen That is what I mean when I say "taking time". "asynchronously" means really no more than that. As my answer illustrates, we go on to the next step in `sendLocationPost` _before_ the operation started in `determineCurrentLocation` has had a chance to update the location.

Comment: Asynchronously means specifically that execution does not block the current thread. Lengthy tasks need not be performed asynchronously.

Comment: @BallpointBen Yup, that's true. But I prefer to be explanatory when dealing with a clear total beginner rather than snowing him with unnecessary technical verbiage.

Comment: I've now realised that when my internet speed isn't great it doesn't get the location the first time around. Is there a way to wait until the locations has been updated before calling sendLocationPost? I've heard semaphores are used for this is that the way to go?

Comment: Absolutely not. Do what Rashwan said. Configure `didUpdateLocations` so that you do the next thing only _when and if_ a good location arrives.